# SVG path 'd' attribute's negative coordinates

Tags: svg, path, coordinates

Why coordinates in d attribute have restrictions to ~(-269000000)?
There is nothing in specification about it.

```css
svg {
  display: block;
}
path {
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: red;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <svg height="1000" width="1000">
      <path d="M0,0L100,100L-268000000,100L100,100">           </path>
      <path d="M100,0L200,200L-269000000,200L200,200">           </path>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Increase coordinate of second path to -268000000 and you will see the second path.

reproduced in
Chrome 62, Safari 11 and Firefox 56

Comment: presumably the underlying operating system has some limitation.

Comment: Displays fine in Windows. What OS are you using?  MacOS?

Comment: Yes, current example is for MacOS.

Comment: But in Windows you can reproduce it too by decreasing the number a little more (-10000000000).